# Can the Tango Tablet be used as a Regular Tablet?

Tags: google-project-tango

Just curious if the Dev Kit Tango Tablet runs Android and/or can do anything else. Short story is I need to get a general use tablet and would like to experiment with a few apps in Tango.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get one , you will certainly not be disapoint by 128gb of storage,
a sim port,a terga k1 with 2.3ghz and 4gb of ram.
So again if you can get one,go on.
Or you can take tango smartphone lenovo phab 2 pro. Good luck